# Is there any alternative to <apex:iframe>?

Tags: apex, visualforce, iframe

I want to display the external website on one of the Salesforce object detail pages via visual force page. But iframe is not working after release 15, As this question has already asked but there is no response.Any help, please.

Answer (score 2):

Take care when talking about releases or versions: "Summer '15" is different from API 15.

This [knowledge article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=IFRAME-or-Web-Tab-Content-Displays-Blank-Page-1327107637323&type=1) explains the reason for the change (security) and offers these two alternatives:

- Display in new window.
- ​Display in existing window without sidebar or header.

The first is the approach I would choose; use an apex:outputLink with a target of "_blank".

Comment: If I use apex:outputLink with a target of '_blank'. it is only redirecting on given website. I want to open this website on my visualforce page as iframe worked.

Comment: @SatyakamSingh The platform blocks the iframe approach as a security measure so what you want can’t be done purely at the browser. You probably could pull the data at the server side but that’s much more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using a VF Page that you own already - you can simply just include the page where you want it using :

```
<apex:include page="pagename" />
```

that would allow you to load your other VF Content here where you want it to be - if it is outside of Salesforce - it must be an https connection and not just an http connection for it to connect in Salesforce.

Comment: I used this but it didn't work for me. Still i am getting blank page